# Uncaught ReferenceError: result is not defined...for displayCars(result);

Tags: jquery, arrays, ajax, json

I have the following snippet of code.  Am getting an Uncaught ReferenceError: result is not defined...for displayCars(result);

The code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

displayCars(result);

function displayCars () {

    $.ajax({
        type : 'GET',
        url : '/modules/crm/selector-ajax.php',
        data : {
            'action' : 'get-images'
        },
        success : function(result) {

            var photoDiv = $('#boat_isotope_gallery');
            var divHtml = '';
            var resultArray = $.parseJSON(result);

            photoDiv.html(divHtml);

        },
        error : function(err) {
            console.log('ajax failure');
        }
    });
}
}); // end of document ready
</script>
```

I've seen the postings about the order of calling scripts.  My scripts are called in a header document.  They are called in the following order and prior to the snippet above:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/tools.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquerymenus.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js">   </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasny-bootstrap/3.1.3/js/jasny-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/2.4.1/lodash.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.isotope/2.0.0/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/2.4.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.2/d3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/selector.js"></script>
```

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: The error was due to result being in displayCars(result);  Using displayCars(); fixed the error.